# Pyinstaller suppress "DeprecationWarning" Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm getting

```
start.py:146: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object
start.py:163: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:483: UserWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:723: UserWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
```

when I compile my .py and I want to find a way to suppress this. I've looked at other threads but all of them seemed to have not worked.

Edit more code:

```
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile)

    profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
    profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
    profile.update_preferences()

    options = FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15')
    options.add_argument('--disable-plugins-discovery')
    options.add_argument('referer=https://www.youtube.com/')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-featuresi=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features')

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
```

Comment: there are problems in your code are you cythonizing it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for fixing error `UserWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead`

you can use the below method

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

then use like this

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id='search']')
```

for error `Firefox DeprecationWarning:`

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile)

profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
profile.update_preferences()
gecko_path = "path_to_geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe"
path = "path_to_firefoxs\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
binary = FirefoxBinary(path)
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15')
options.add_argument('--disable-plugins-discovery')
options.add_argument('referer=https://www.youtube.com/')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-featuresi=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, executable_path=gecko_path)
```

in addition, you can add your firefox profile directly like this

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/x/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/some-long-string')

profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
profile.update_preferences()
gecko_path = "path_to_geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe"
path = "path_to_firefoxs\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
binary = FirefoxBinary(path)
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15')
options.add_argument('--disable-plugins-discovery')
options.add_argument('referer=https://www.youtube.com/')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-featuresi=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, executable_path=gecko_path)
```

Comment: still having the issue?

Comment: For XPATH, no but still need help with firefox profiles and such